# How to remove year in DateFormat follower locale?

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I use DateFormat to show Day and Month. DateFormat supports MEDIUM, LONG, FULL all have a year. I want to remove year from this code and how can I achieve this

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = (SimpleDateFormat) DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG, locale);
sdf.applyPattern(sdf.toPattern().replaceAll("[^\\p{Alpha}]*y+[^\\p{Alpha}]*", ""));
```

But I get an error with some locale like:

> bo_CN : སྤྱི་ལོ་y MMMMའི་ཙེས་dད
>
> vi: 'Ngày' dd 'tháng' MM 'năm' y
>
> se_SE: d 'de' MMMM 'de' y

Comment: It's really a bad idea using a Regex trying to remove the year from a string which could be really different for alla the locales in the world. You should end up building your string piece to piece, appending only the values you need to a StringBuilder

Comment: Hm, `SimpleDateFormat` does not have such an option so only a potential unsafe workaround like regex or similar is left. However, if you don't mind to add an extra dependency, you could also import my library Time4A and the misc-module of Time4J, and then use the class `AnnualDate`. Its [javadoc](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/xml/AnnualDate.html) shows how to achieve a localized month-day-combination without year.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleDateFormat:

`Date date = new Date();
java.text.SimpleDateFormat df = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd");
String dateString = df.format(date);`

Output:

01/21

Comment: This solution is not localizable. Please be so kind to read the question again. The OP wants to have a generic solution without the assumption that month and day-of-month have to be printed as "MM/dd".

Comment: DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM", new Locale("EN"));
String date = df.format(new Date());

Comment: Your pattern would be wrong for most regions of the world. Just try for Chinese, German etc. Those patterns look different than you think. The question is not about concrete patterns which are known in advance at compile time. The correct solution must start with something similar to `DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG, locale);`

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code

```
String shortDate = "dd.MM";
String mediumDate = "MMM dd";
String longDate = "MMMM dd";
String fullDate = "EEEE, MMMM dd";
    
Locale locale = new Locale("EN"); 
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(fullDate, locale); \\Use the required format here
String formattedDate = df.format(new Date());
```

I have removed the year part and created custom equivalent of

> `DateFormat.SHORT` as `shortDate`
>
> `DateFormat.MEDIUM` as `mediumDate`
>
> `DateFormat.LONG` as `longDate`
>
> `DateFormat.FULL` as `fullDate`